# Mock Hibernate entityManager with createQuery(), parameters and executeUpdate()

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, mockito, junit5

I'm new on Unit Testing in java; I've an application that uses Hibernate to interact with a MySQL database.

I have many queries built with `createQuery()` method, also with parameters, like the following one:

```java
return this.entityManager.createQuery("from MyEntity m where param  = :param", MyEntity.class)
    .setParameter("param", param)
    .getSingleResult();
```

I would like to avoid to mock all the subsequent calls on the `entityManager` object, because sometimes I've query with more than 5 parameters and seems not that handy to mock each of those calls.

The same concept can be applied on [Builder objects](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternBuilder/article.html).

**Edit 1**

I add a concrete example of what I use (given that it's not a good way to manage exception, but unluckly is quiet usual):

```
public class MyService {
private EntityManager entityManager;

public MyEntity find(String field ) {
        try{
            return this.entityManager.createQuery("from MyEntity  c where c.field = :field ", MyEntity .class)
                    .setParameter("field ", field )
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (NonUniqueResultException e) {
            logger.error("find", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, given the behavior of the call on `entityManager`  I have different branches to be tested. Then I have to mock the answer of that call to test all the lines of this method.

### What I found

What I found was the following:

```java
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Which works as expected. I can mock all the calls' chain. **BUT**

1. Citing from the [Javadoc of Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS):

> WARNING: This feature should rarely be required for regular clean code! Leave it for legacy code. Mocking a mock to return a mock, to return a mock, (...), to return something meaningful hints at violation of Law of Demeter or mocking a value object (a well known anti-pattern).

2. If the previous point wasn't enough, the next one, some lines after, clearly set a big limitation:

> This feature will not work when any return type of methods included in the chain cannot be mocked (for example: is a primitive or a final class). This is because of java type system.

The second point means that if I try to mock in this way the method `executeUpdate()`, which returns an `int`, it raise an exception.

```java
when(entityManager.createQuery(anyString())
                .setParameter(eq("param"), anyString())
                .executeUpdate())
.thenReturn(1);
```

and in that way I can't test the interactions with the `entityManager`.

### Questions

1. How should I mock the calls on `entityManager`? It seems impossible to me that I have to mock each method one by one.
2. Is wrong to use `Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`? If not, how can I handle the second example?

Comment: My advice would be to test the code interacting with `EntityManager` (or any other external, low-level API) using integration tests exclusively. Trying to mock it for unit tests is a waste of time, and queries are only reliably tested using integration tests anyway. If you have an abstraction over the `EntityManager` API (e.g. a `Dao` object), *that layer* you can easily mock for your other unit tests

Comment: counter-question: why mock the entity manager in the firist place? Why not test against a database, e.g. an in-memory h2 or a fully-fledged database started via testcontainers? The "unit" in "unit test" does not necessarily mean "class".

Comment: @crizzis There is no dao. Services access directly to the entityManager. I'll update the question with a code example. Note that this pattern is used in hundreds of classes, thousands of methods, on many and many projects, so it can't be changed :)

Comment: @Turing85 Because if I got right unit test not concern databases or external api calls or something like that. But I'm asking because I have to learn, so every advice is a good start!

Comment: As nice as the idea of being database-agnostic is, in 99% of all cases you have - in one way or another - bind to a specific DBMS (e.g. indexes are not defined in ANSI-SQL) and the exceptions thrown (at least the messages) will varry between implementations. In that regard, I would recommend testing the persistence layer with the actual DBMS(es) that are used / will be used in production. This comes at the cost of filling the database with test data, of course.

Comment: In my case the majority of services' methods interact directly with the `EntityManager` instance. Seems like this is a situation in which mocks should do the job, without have a database that contains information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mock the JPA API, just write integration tests with proper test data and execute the real queries against real data to see if everything works. Projects like [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) make it very easy to get started.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then I should not do unit test where I use the entityManager? Consider that we don't have DAOs which split access to db and service logic. Seems like I can't do unit test everywhere I interact with entityManager (almost everywhere in different services).

Comment: Given that probably if we use JPA and not only Hibernate the situation would be better, is it possible to mock entityManager method chain to return what I need to unit test my method logic?

Comment: IMO a test can still be considered a "unit test" if you use a database behind the scenes, so just use the database and execute the queries against that. Unless you try to test a presentation layer, it makes no sense to mock a data layer and even then I wouldn't mock that. Testing the real thing, although it might be a bit slower (but not that much), will always give you higher confidence.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this suggestion. If I understood well, I should unit test all methods which doesn't interact with database/entityManager, while in integration test I test all methods which does it. For IT is ok to have some methods from service layer tested through API and other tested on the service's IT class or it's not a good pattern? Because I would test methods of the same class in different places and perhaps can be confusing.

Comment: There rarely is a "true unit" that you test. You always take a few things as granted i.e. the things you use for implementing the test. The unit usually also uses libraries, but is it an integration test because of that? No. The distinction between unit and integration test somewhat blur when you view it this way. I think separating tests into fast and slow categories would be more appropriate. But believe me, you can make tests that use DBs very fast, so I personally consider them "unit tests" most of the time.